# add characters to end of line

Tags: actionscript

How do I add `</in>` to the end of each line?

A String contain:

```
<ch>13</ch><in>Item 13(mono)

<ch>14</ch><in>Item 14(mono)

<ch>15</ch><in>Item 15(mono)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace each line break with `</in>` and a line break, you could try something like this:

```
myString = myString.replace(/\n/g, "</in>\n");
```

But if the strings contains the extra white space, extra empty lines, in your example, you would probably end up with an extra `</in>` there too. So to get valid XML, you would probably have to do more than the above.